# implement carbon to compare date (API)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
public function searchresult (Request $request)
{
    $keyword = $request->name;

    $search = Mosque::where('name', 'LIKE',"%{$keyword}%" )
        ->whereHas('events')
        ->orWhereHas('activities')
        ->get();

    return response()->json(['result' => $search]);    
}
```

//model mosque

```
class Mosque extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'state_id',
        'area_id',
        'name',
        'latitude',
        'longitude',
        'address',
        'image',
        'type',
        'referral_code',
        'phone_number_1',
        'phone_number_2',
        'deleted_at'
    ];

    public function events()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
    }

    public function activities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Activity');
    }
}
```

This is my controller for search. the relation is the mosque has many events and activity. in the activities and events, I have column start date and end date. how I implement carbon to compare today date with the start date and compare today date with end date which will give the result only the mosque that has an event and activity between start date and end date. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `whereHas()` relationships you can provide a `closure` like this.

Possible solution.

```
$search = Mosque::where('name', 'LIKE',"%{$keyword}%" )
    ->whereHas('events', function($query) {
        query->where([
            ['start_date', '<=' Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d')]
            ['end_date', '>=' Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d')]
        ]);
    })
    ->orWherehas('activities', function($query) {
        query->where([
            ['start_date', '<=' Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d')]
            ['end_date', '>=' Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d')]
        ]);
    })
    ->get();
```

Note that the `start_date` and `end_date` have to be of `date or timestamps` otherwise if they are `text` you would need to typecast them first

Comment: i think syntax error on $query->where([
            ['start_date', '<=' Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d')]
            ['end_date', '>=' Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d')]
        ]); still checking @Tharaka Dilshan

Comment: be careful to match my code with your variable names, your table column names. because this is an example.

Comment: hi bro its working only need some adjustment  and fix some syntax where query->where([
            ['start_date', '<=' , Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d')],
            ['end_date', '>=' , Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d')]
        ]); @TharakaDilshan